# questDB 7.1.1 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: questdb

I am trying one of the latest features of QuestDB (v7.1.1).

Connecting to questdb using Npgsql in C#: the request SELECT * FROM table_partitions('F-WWCT_adc')
does not work and the log report i.q.c.p.PGWireServer internal error [ex=
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException ...

The same request within questDB console works fine.

Same issue with SHOW PARTITIONS FROM 'F-WWCT_adc';

My connection is OK as other basics request (show tables, SELECT * FROM 'F-WWCT_adc', ..) are working.

I would expect the same result as the console

Did anybody has the same issue ?

Comment: It can be a bug, feel free to create a GitHub issue at https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues with the exception call stack ideally

Comment: Done, they tagged it as a BUG.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in table_partitions() function triggered most likely by binary mode in pg wire . [This pull request](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/pull/3251) should fix it.